# When is it possible to swap expander and compressor?

Tags: multirate

In the figure below I want to know when is it possible to swap expander and compressor so that the outputs remain the same?

[image]

I know in general it's not possible to interchange because neither expander nor compressor are TI but I know in some cases it's possible.

Comment: Don't you want to swap the down-sampler and the up-sampler in the second picture? Currently the two block diagrams are identical so yo have automatically $y_a = y_b$

Comment: @Hilmar, thank you :), I made a mistake, i changed it.

Comment: As said, these are down/upsampling or decimation/interpolation; expanding and compression are different things, as far as I know. In which context did you see these two terms used?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, this names is used by oppenheim in his book.

Comment: Oppenheim's *Signals and Systems* or *Discrete-Time signal processing*? Could you tell me the chapter, please?

Comment: @m-sh-shokouhi nevermind, found it! Interesting! I've never seen it used like that!